# How to resolve quality check issue in audeince network for android apps ?

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network, facebook-monetization-manager

I have googled everywhere but can't find proper answer.

My all **android apps** falling in **failing** state under **quality check**. How to resolve this problem in **facebook monetization manager** ?

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: I have googled everywhere but still no solution found. I have also contacted facebook support team but as usual bot response, they not giving proper solution of what coding we have to change.

Comment: did you check the quality check page from the menu -> Integration?
https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/770180493117128?

Comment: Yes @Fallen , I have check complete documentation. Try all the way , but still not figure out problem. They have incomplete guide and incomplete troubleshooter to solve problem.

Comment: Still this issue exist. Following the guideline to the point has no effect. Anyone find anything?

Comment: No @Tahlil , They have still not figured out this thing. many of us left because of this issue and poor support on this.

Comment: @UmeshDevani did you resolved the issue  Facing The Same Issue...?

Comment: @MushtaqRahim Not yet

Answer (score 0):

It's being switched between pass and fail for simple banner integration.

Answer (score -1):

Your app needs to be compliant with all things listed. I failed to comply by not adding privacy policy and there appeared crash on most devices that I didn't test. Got approved through the fixes and appeal I made.